# Incident duration prediction but online with trend

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, regression, statistics

I am currently looking into some papers discussing `Incident duration prediction`. The dataset consists of ca. 250 monitored events. For all of those incidents are multiple features available and the main goal is the prediction of the `incident duration`. These durations are right-skewed and log-normal distributed. ANOVA test (and KS) identified 13 binary features to be independent.

To predict the durations the researchers compared `Multiple linear regression`, `DT`, `ANN`, `SVM / RVM` and `KNN`.

Currently, I am looking into a way to transfer the knowledge from this case to another task. Predicting the duration of incidents in an **online system** (online in the sense of continuous flow of information) and also accounting for **trends** (e.g. increasing duration of incidents because it is getting darker or colder at the same time throughout different seasons).

Unfortunately, there is such a huge amount of methods besides the mentioned methods (non-parametric, hazard models, reliability models, etc) - it seems like a jungle